# get other site's elements

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to use a not local site as a source for my own? For example get a price from an e-shop everytime my site refreshes.

Is it possible to use something similar to this but somehow from a custom source?

`document.getElementsByClassName('price')[0]`

Comment: Yes, by using `fetch` to make a request to an external site then adding that content to a DOM fragment and parsing it. Note that if a site is configured to block `fetch` requests from other websites then browsers will honour that. Also, for security reasons browsers won't send cookies to external websites using `fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly inside a browser, at least not without great effort. Browsers take great pains to try to isolate sites from each other to prevent attacks called CSRF. 
If you are running a system like nodejs or php to build your system, you can run a cron process to go fetch the price you need and embed it into your source.

I usually use python when I want to scrape a site, but most common programming languages will have libraries to import data from a url.